# `elementToBeClickable` just checks that it's visible and enabled

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very beginner and using Selenium and Java to write a test, sometimes the web element that I need to click on is covered by others and according to [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2139) right now `elementToBeClickable` just checks that it's visible and enabled. Any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `elementToBeClickable` just checks that it's visible and enabled

This is definitely true - the expected condition is not based on the actual [Element Displayedness](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-displayedness) - but, `isDisplayed()` is entirely based on the mentioned WebDriver spec - call it inside the custom Expected Condition:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> isDisplayed(final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {

        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(locator); 
            if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                return element;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(isDisplayed(By.id("myid")));
```

Comment: the link to Element Displayedness  is broken

Comment: element.isDisplayed() returns a boolean, but the method is expecting a return of a WebElement.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is encountered on sites where, for example, there is a fixed header (meaning that when you scroll the page the header will not remain at the top of the page and be invisible, but will always be visible). One example would be the Facebook header (the blue header on top that contains the search bar).

I've encountered this several times, and it seems that the element is visible and enabled even if it's located right under that header.

To overcome this, you can use the move to an element that is located higher than the one that you want to click. You can achieve this by using the `Actions` class.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
//The element situated higher than the one you need to click
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```